# Run a script on startup to periodically disable the keyboard

Tags: scripts, startup

I have the following script

```
  while [ true ]
    do
      gnome-screensaver-command -l
      xinput set-int-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 8 0
      sleep 1m
      xinput set-int-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 8 1
      sleep 30m
  done
```

I want to run it on startup. I have really bad neck pain so doctor suggested me to go for a walk or do minor exercise every 30 minutes or so. I created this script which will lock me out and disable mouse for one minute. I also want to add keyboard disabling which will totally lock me out of my computer for a minute. It would be really amazing if there is any better option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've got a really good reason to make something new (some people do), I'd look at existing applications that do what you're asking.

Gnome [used to have a Typing Break feature](http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2007/07/03/prevent-repetitive-strain-injury-rsi-take-a-timed-break-with-standard-gnome-software/) but that was six years ago and that's a lot of time when developers are hell-bent on ripping out all the useful features. It might still be there. (Pre-post-edit: Yeah, looks like this was nuked in 2010/11. Sigh.)

RSI is a long-standing issue so there are other applications that do what you want:

- [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/download/) is probably the best option. More configuration than Typing Break and it allows you to do exactly what you're asking (it'll blank out the screen and disable input). It's also in the repos.
- [drwright](https://live.gnome.org/drwright) is a port of Typing Break for Gnome 3 stuff but it *should* work in Unity too. You'll need to add a PPA (on the page) to install it but that's not a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add the  keyboard to it, you can use a very similar method to  what you already have.

Go to a terminal and type `xinput`. This will show you the id numbers for all your input devices. In my case, my keyboard appears as "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard",   id=12; so in my case I would add the lines

`xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0`

and

`xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 1`

into the respective places in the script. Just substitute "12" for whatever ID your keyboard appears as in `xinput`.

As for running the script on startup; you will need a first line saying `#!/bin/bash`.

Assuming it is called `lockmeout.sh`, copy it to your home directory (`~`) and then do `chmod +x ~/lockmeout.sh`. Then, open "Startup applications" (available by typing "startup" in the dash), and add an entry that points to that script. Now it should execute whenever you log in, and stay running in the background.

Hope this helps!